# Design a good structure data in my database on Firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a tracker gps app and before create a Database on Firebase, I would like to know your opinions.

First of all, I going to explain my app.

1. You must login with facebook or google (get id --primary key)
2. You can add/edit your personal profile (get profile frome facebook or google and later,you can edit it)
3. You must add dogs (at last one)
4. You register a new activity.This activity draw a polyline on a map and register your time and your walk distance.
5. Later, you will be able to get all of your activitys and watch it.

Finaly, I want to save all info in a Firebase Database.

How do you design this database?

My opinion:

- IdNumber (Primary Key)

  - Name
  - Surname
  - City
  - Country
  - Activity

    - Date
    - Distance
    - Time
    - Locations (Arraylist of locations)
    - Dog

Thanks for your help! I´m really lost with this, its my first database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation there will be multiple dogs and multiple activities. So both will be a list. I think your database needs to look something like this:

- IdNumber (Primary Key)

  - Name
  - Surname
  - City
  - Country
  - Dogs

    - Dog1

      - Name
      - Age
      - Type
    - Dog2

      - Name
      - Age
      - Type
  - Activities

    - Activity1

      - Date
      - Distance
      - Time
      - Locations (Arraylist of locations)
      - DogID
    - Activity2

      - Date
      - Distance
      - Time
      - Locations (Arraylist of locations)
      - DogID